# Problems with Scala Play Framework Slick Session

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I'm creating an application in Scala using Play 2.2. I'm using `play-slick 0.5.0.8` as my MySQL DB connector. I have the following application controller:

```
package controllers

import models._
import models.database._

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.slick._

object Application extends Controller {
  // WORKS:
  def test = DBAction {
    implicit session => Ok(views.html.test(Cameras.findById(1)))
  }

  // DOES NOT WORK:
  def photo = Action {
    val p = PhotoFetcher.fetchRandomDisplayPhoto(someParametersBlah))
    Ok(views.html.photo(p))
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `test` DBAction works, and it's able to fetch a photo from the DB just fine. Unfortunately, the `photo` Action does not work.

My `PhotoFetcher.fetchRandomDisplayPhoto(blah)` does a bunch of different things. Buried inside of it is a call to `Cameras.findById(blah)`, which should return a `Camera` object (which works in the `test` DBAction). However, with this configuration I get the following error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter s: slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple.Session
```

I have tried making the `photo` Action into a DBAction, like so:

```
def photo = DBAction {
  implicit session => {
    val p = PhotoFetcher.fetchRandomDisplayPhoto(someParametersBlah))
    Ok(views.html.photo(p))
  }
}
```

But that just results in the same missing session error. It's like PhotoFetcher doesn't know about the implicit session.

The other thing I've tried is importing `slick.session.Database.threadLocalSession` in my `PhotoFetcher`, but that only results in the following error:

```
SQLException: No implicit session available; threadLocalSession can only be used within a withSession block
```

If it's any help, this is a simplified version of my `Cameras` object:

```
package models.database

import models.Format.Format
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

case class Camera(id: Long,
                  otherStuff: String)

trait CamerasComponent {
  val Cameras: Cameras

  class Cameras extends Table[Camera]("cameras") {
    def id          = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def otherStuff  = column[String]("otherStuff", O.NotNull)

    def * = id ~ otherStuff <> (Camera.apply _, Camera.unapply _)

    val byId         = createFinderBy(_.id)
    val byOtherStuff = createFinderBy(_.otherStuff)
  }
}

object Cameras extends DAO {
  def insert(camera: Camera)(implicit s: Session) { Cameras.insert(camera) }
  def findById(id: Long)(implicit s: Session): Option[Camera] = Cameras.byId(id).firstOption
  def findByOtherStuff(otherStuff: String)(implicit s: Session): Option[Camera] = Cameras.byOtherStuff(model).firstOption
}
```

So, it seems as if I've gotten crossed-up somewhere. Right now it's only possible for me to access my DAO objects directly from a Controller DBAction, and not from inside of some different class. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your definition of `PhotoFetcher.fetchRandomDisplayPhoto.fetchRandomDisplayPhoto` take an implicit session?

```
 // PhotoFetcher
 def fetchRandomDisplayPhoto(args: Blah*)(implicit s: Session) = {
   // ...
   val maybeCam = Cameras.findById(blah) // <- sees the implicit session 
   // ...
 }
```

Or are you relying on a `threadLocalsession` in `PhotoFetcher`? (no implicit session argument for `fetchRandomDisplayPhoto`)?

While Slick's threadLocalSession is handy for quickly trying out stuff, it can lead to confusion and loss of clarity later on.  It's best to just use explicit `(implicit s: Session)` parameter lists for all methods that call your Slick models. This also plays 
well with `DBAction`, letting the framework manage sessions.

The downside is you have to have `(implicit s: Session)` on all your methods - there 
are workarounds like this: 
https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/issues/20

Scala isn't verbose and is very amenable to refactoring - so I'd recommend thinking
about crossing that bridge when you come to it, and use `DBAction` for all actions
that do database stuff; give all methods that call your database models an 
implicit session, and see how much that mileage that gives you.

Comment: Explicit implicits... ironic.