# Passing Slick 2.0 implicit session in elegant way

Tags: scala, session, playframework, slick, implicit

I'm new to Slick and Scala. First of take a look at my example table with case class mapping and helper for queries `SuitsManager`. Now methods of `SuitsManager` are called by Play! controllers inside DBAction (I'm using play-slick 0.6.0.1).

```
package models

import play.api.db.slick._
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._

import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
import scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend

case class Suit(id:Option[Long],
                complainant: String,
                defender: String,
                litigation: Long,
                litigationValue: BigDecimal,
                status: Long)

class Suits(tag: Tag) extends Table[Suit](tag, "SUITS") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def complainant = column[String]("complainant")
  def defender = column[String]("defender")
  def litigation = column[Long]("litigation")
  def litigationValue = column[BigDecimal]("litigationValue")
  def status = column[Long]("status")

  def * = (id.?, complainant, defender, litigation, litigationValue, status) <> (Suit.tupled, Suit.unapply)

}

object SuitsManager {
  val suits = TableQuery[Suits]

  def list(offset: Int, limit: Int, filter: String = "%")(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session) = {
    suits.filter(_.defender like "%").drop(offset).take(limit).list
  }

  def count(offset: Int, limit: Int, filter: String = "%") : Long = {    
    suits.filter(_.defender like "%").drop(offset).take(limit).length.run
  }
}
```

Now take a look at 2 methods in `SuitsController` the first one compiles because it declares implicit session parameter. The second one gives compile error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter session: play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.Backend#Session
```

So creating helper objects for queries seems to be not very elegant. Is there any other way do it without declaring implicit session parameter? Maybe using an import? My second question: is the session parameter type `JdbcBackend#Session` correct? Why not just Session?

Comment: Ok, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19492407/831826. This answer states that declaring implicit session param is recommended. Is it also true for Slick 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First question:**
It is not possible to avoid passing around the `Session` in some way.

The implicit `Session` you pass around is not some global information of your application. The `Session` object represents the *current* open session you have with the database. With Play Slick, this database session is opened for you when a request is made to a `DBAction`.

That means that your `Session` is only available, and strictly tied to, an HTTP request. In fact, you'll find that it is a field of the `implicit request =>` you note in every `DBAction`:

```
val someAction = DBAction { implicit request =>      // DBAction opens database session, and puts it in request.dbSession
   // Database session for this request is implicitly available on
   // the scope here and therefore may be passed to other methods implicitly
}  // Database session is closed
```

So you have a new and different database session for every request. Furthermore, every database interaction requires a database session. Therefore, every method that executes some query therefore needs to be provided with the current `Session` you have for processing your particular request.

The reason implicits are usually used for this is because it provides the cleanest code for passing around this session.

```
// With implicits
def helperMethod1(param: Any)(implicit s: Session) = someQuery1.list // Session is passed implicitly 
def helperMethod2(param: Any)(implicit s: Session) = someQuery2.exists.run // Session is passed implicitly

def action = DBAction { implicit request =>
   // Stuff
   helperMethod1(param1) // request.dbSession is passed implicitly
   // Stuff
   helperMethod2(param2) // request.dbSession is passed implicitly
   // Stuff
}
```

Versus the more repetitive

```
// Without implicits
def helperMethod1(param: Any, s: Session) = someQuery.list(s)  // Must pass Session explicitly
def helperMethod2(param: Any, s: Session) = someQuery.exists.run(s)

def action = DBAction { implicit request =>
   val session = request.dbSession
   // Stuff
   helperMethod1(param1, session) // Have to repeat session for every DB call
   // Stuff
   helperMethod2(param2, session)
   // Stuff
}
```

The example in the Slick documentation question that @cvogt mentions is not a good solution to your problem, as it does not reduce the amount of arguments you need to pass around in this case.

**Second question:**
In general, `Session` is a so-called type alias for for `JdbcBackend#Session`. That means that `type Session = JdbcBackend#Session`, i.e. they're exactly the same. You can safely use `Session` in any code except, unfortunately, Play controller code.

The reason for this is that Play controllers also define a type `Session`. Play's `Session` represents the current HTTP session, based on the cookies the user has set. Unfortunately, this naming clashes with Slick's `Session`.

To work around this, you can alias the import: `import scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile.simple.{Session => SlickSession}`.

Comment: Ok got it. From slick documentation: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/connection.html#passing-sessions-around "Or you can bundle several such methods into a class, which stores the session to reduce boilerplate code". I could change `SuitsManager` from object to class and declare it: `class SuitsManager (implicit session: Session)` it would reduce the boilerplate code in each method that way. But then I would need to create an instance of `SuitsManager` per each DBAction request. I that correct?

Comment: @Sebastian Please accept this answer if you think it answered your questions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a helper class and session an argument of the class, if the repetition bothers you. It's explained here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/connection.html#passing-sessions-around

The import-solution you suggested exists as well, but it is less typesafe. See: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/connection.html#dynamically-scoped-sessions

Session is a path-dependent type in the Slick driver cake (as in cake pattern), that's why it needs to be accessed via the # operator